# json jquery format issue

Tags: jquery, json

this is my code on server side

```
$results = array();
while($rw = $objS->row($rs))
 {
$results[]=array('id'=>$rw["id"],
'agent_id'=>$rw["agent_id"],
'agent'=>$rw["agent"]);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

on client side i have this coding

```
success: function( data ) {
var forum = data.results;
for(i = 0, l = forum.length; i < l; i++) {
row = forum[i];
alert(row.id);
}
```

how to develop json on server side?
my json returns is

```
[{"id":"1","agent_id":"1","agent":"Rustomadmin"}]
```

i need like this

```
{"results":[{"id":1,"agent_id":"888","agent":"Emili"}]}
```

Comment: You need it like that because your client-side code accesses `data.results`. Maybe you can just write `var forum = data;` instead, or simply use `data` directly?

Comment: alert(data) give me [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Yes, it is an array of two objects, the same thing `data.results` would have given you if your server-side code generated a `results` object. Try using `data` directly instead of `forum` in your loop.

Comment: @user2244804 : You said, the problem only from `server side`, then whats the reason to discuss on `client side script`.. Is there also any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array()` declaration is totally wrong.. Try this..

To populate multiple record values means,

```
<?php
    while($rw = $objS->row($rs))
     {
       $results[] = $rw;         // It generate Array of Array
     }

   $agentResult['results']  = $results;

   $jsonResult = json_encode($agentResult);
  echo $jsonResult;
?>
```

Comment: sir this is also not working...sir how to create it exactly like this...{"results":[{"id":1,"agent_id":"888","agent":"Emili"}]}

Comment: this is good,but i want to add another query in while loop and get some value and want to pass in result array also..